# I have problems with understanding mechanism beyond urls

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-router-v4

When I am using create-react-app for building and serving the app, I don't have problems with hitting particular url throw the browser url line. But when I using my own webpack config, this requests go to the backend calls. What is the trick?

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    client: "./src/client/index.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: { loader: "babel-loader" }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "html-loader" }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          { loader: "resolve-url-loader" },
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg|pdf|ico)$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'file-loader' },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/client/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ],
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api/**': {
        target: 'http://localhost:1337',
        secure: false,
      }
    }
  },
};

<Router history={history}>
      <App />
</Router>
```

I want behavior like in create-react-app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "trick" resides in `.htaccess`, not Webpack:

**.htaccess for react-router**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
 </IfModule>
```